# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance

Tags: android

I am trying to **dismiss class 0 message dialogs** which are also called system alert dialogs using `AccessibilityService` class. These dialogs are mainly used by SIM operators to notify the user in response to a request they made. I am trying to perform a global back action in `onAccessibilityEvent()` method to dismiss the dialog using the following code:

```java
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {      
    if(event.getClassName().toString().equals("android.app.AlertDialog")){
        event.setAction(AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an `IllegalStateException`. Here is the complete error log:

```java
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance.
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.enforceNotSealed(AccessibilityRecord.java:666)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.setAction(AccessibilityEvent.java:810)
at com.example.class0message.RecorderService.onAccessibilityEvent(RecorderService.java:52)
at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$1.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:518)
at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below:

```
performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK);
```